# Invalid service file "core/core.services.yml"

Tags: drupal-8, dev-to-production

I am trying to push a drupal 8 project into production but I am running into an error stated below.

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: The service file "core/core.services.yml" is not valid. in Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\YamlFileLoader->loadFile() (line 329 of /usr/www/users/playsgwjrd/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/YamlFileLoader.php).
```

I have tried running build.php, removing the lock composer file and vendor folder but nothing.

```
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\YamlFileLoader->loadFile('core/core.services.yml') (Line: 63)
Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\YamlFileLoader->load('core/core.services.yml') (Line: 1316)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->compileContainer() (Line: 920)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 476)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 692)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 23)
```

Please suggest ways on going about to fix the error.

Comment: Did you or anybody changed the file `core/core.services.yml`? Can you show the content of that file?

Comment: Hi @KoalaYeung. Thanks for your reply.

Below is the link to the service.yml file content.

https://github.com/Thomas-Chirwa/drupal

Comment: Your question reads "unable to locate the service file “core/core.services.yml”" but your error says it has problem with the file content instead. Which is actually your problem?

Comment: Hi @KoalaYeung, sorry about that. The problem is as stated in the error message, the problem with the file content.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the solution in the below URL helps. You will need to apply the patch:

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3007298

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was serving up drupal via PHP CLI and had to be running it in the web folder, not send web/index.php as a param